# woocommerce validate user name and password via rest api

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am developing an android app for an eCommerce site that is built in wp-woocommerce.
I really don't know much about wp.
I have read http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/ and have developed almost all the android app. but I was unable to find a way to validate the username and password of the customer via rest API.
I just want to pass the username and password and expect the result as pass or fail.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, WooCommerce REST API doesn't deal with login/logout (customers) as they are treated as WordPress users with CUSTOMER roles.

The API KEY and SECRETE is for your app to fetch data as products - orders etc... You have to use WordPress API login methods to access user information, signup new users/customers,.

[WordPress REST API / Auth](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)

If you prefer to use JWT there is many plugins in the plugins repo.[I have used this one: Simple JWT Login – Login and Register to WordPress using JWT](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-jwt-login/) and works good.